# (Sudden) Weird behavior of M-q in auctex

Tags: auctex, formatting, fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

I very much enjoying using the auto fill functionality that the key binding <kbd>M-q</kbd> provides. However, starting recently, I am experiencing a small (but annoying) change in its behavior when in LaTeX mode. That is, now I have to explicitly mark the paragraph that I want to auto fill, whereas before it was good enough as long as the cursor is somewhere in the paragraph. For example,  to format

```
Hello 
World
```

to

```
Hello World
```

it was enough to hit <kbd>M-q</kbd> with my cursor somewhere in those two lines. Now I have to mark the two lines and then hit <kbd>M-q</kbd> to get the reformatting. I haven't installed anything new or touched my configuration file. I did update Emacs a couple days ago. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out that this was happening because I was in the "appendices" environment, but still finding a way to make this not happen in the "appendices" environment.

Comment: When you have your .tex file opened, what is the value of the variable `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` in that buffer?.  You can check it with `C-h v LaTeX-indent-environment-list RET`.  Do you see an entry for `appendices`?

Comment: Yes, I see ("appendices" current-indentation), which I think I added in an attempt to solve the issue. Also, not sure if relevant, but while I can use the appendices environment without any issue but auctex won't autocomplete appendices unlike other environments such as align, equation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries in `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` control the filling behavior in environments.  If you want the standard filling AUCTeX applies to environments, remove entries for your `appendices` from it and <kbd>M-q</kbd> should work again.

The `appendices` environment is provided by LaTeX package `appendix.sty`.  In order to get auto-completion for it when you hit <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>, you need a small AUCTeX style `appendix.el` which makes the addition to AUCTeX.  Such a style can look like this:

```el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "appendix"
 (lambda ()

   (TeX-add-symbols
    "appendixpage"
    "addappheadtotoc"
    "noappendicestocpagenum"
    "appendicestocpagenum"
    "appendixname"
    "appendixtocname"
    "appendixpagename"

    "appendixtocon"
    "appendixtocoff"
    "appendixpageon"
    "appendixpageoff"
    "appendixtitleon"
    "appendixtitleoff"
    "appendixtitletocon"
    "appendixtitletocoff"
    "appendixheaderon"
    "appendixheaderoff"
    "restoreapp"

    "setthesection"
    "setthesubsection")

   (LaTeX-add-environments
    '("appendices")
    '("subappendices"))

   ;; Don't indent the content inside \(sub\)?appendices environments:
   (unless (string-match "appendices" LaTeX-document-regexp)
     (set (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-document-regexp)
          (concat LaTeX-document-regexp "\\|\\(?:sub\\)?appendices"))))
 LaTeX-dialect)

(defvar LaTeX-appendix-package-options '("toc" "page" "title"
                                         "titletoc" "header")
  "Package options for the appendix package.")
```

Set the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.

```el
(setq TeX-style-private
      '("~/.emacs.d/auctex-styles"))
```

and save the code above there as `appendix.el`.  Now re-start Emacs and open your .tex file.  If you have this in your init file as well

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

the auto-completion should be available directly.

Comment: I'll try this tonight. Thanks for the comment. Regarding autocomplete,  I didn't have to go through any of that for the amsmath environments and autocomplete still works well - why is the appendix package special in this aspect? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so your suggestion kind of solved the issue, but now the tab key indents everything in the appendices environment - can I make this not happen? I just want the appendices environment to work like the "document" environment without any special indentation or whatsoever. Thanks!

Comment: @apprentice - Can't reproduce what you describe.  The form `(unless (string-match "appendices" LaTeX-document-regexp) (set (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-document-regexp) ...)` does exactly what you're asking for.  Hit `C-h e` when you've opened your .tex file and see if `appendix.el` is loaded.  Also check the value of the variable`LaTeX-document-regexp` in the buffer.

Comment: I had to add appendices to the variable to LaTeX-verbatim-environments. Everything works like a charm now. So the bottom line is: do NOT add appdendices to  LaTeX-indent-environment-list, but add it to LaTeX-verbatim-environments. Thanks for all the help!